# How to Create a dask dataframe from from a data string seperated by tabs and new line characters

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask-ml

I've my data in form of a string seperated by \ character (for columns) & by new line \n character for rows.

```
ID\Product\quantity\n1\xx\2
```

Looks like Dask.array.from_array() support only a array as input.

Although I can convert the above text to np.array using

```
np.array([i.split("\t") for i in data[1].split("\n")])
```

Wondering if there is something equivalent to directly convert the string into dask array or dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You may want the dask.dataframe.read_csv function

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('filename.*.csv', sep='\t')
```